# Is it safe to delete a Bamboo agent's folder in xml-data\build-dir\?

Tags: bamboo

For Bamboo server, in the xml-data\build-dir\ folder, there are folders with numbers for names that I believe correspond to each local agent (I have 25 agents, and 25 folders in this directory, one for each agent). I want to clear the contents of this entire working directory on a regular basis. If I delete these agent folders, will the bamboo agents simply create new ones here the next time they need to?

I know there's been discussions about how to clean up the working directory on the Atlassian forums, but this is a question more about how bamboo actually works. Do the agents depend on those folders being there, or will an agent create a folder in xml-data\build-dir\ if the previous one has been deleted?

Answer (score 0):

It when you clean ob the directories from the build jobs, bamboo will create new ones when the agent start to build them.